# CSS Pseudo Class hover properties

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the color of text to "white" when mouse is hovered on the background image or when its hovered on the `div`. I know that I'd have to use `Pseudo` class combination for this but just can't figure it out. Its got to be something very simple I know.

Here's the code.

```css
.bigbox {
 border-bottom: 6px solid #00a37a;
  position:relative;
  

}
.bigbox:hover {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ee5630;
  
}

.h2title {
 padding-left:70px;
  margin-top:200px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:11;
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
  
}

.img2 {
  opacity:0.2;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.img2:hover {
  opacity:0.9;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.img2 + h2title:hover {
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox">
    <a class="h2title" href="#"> <h2> Some Text</h2></a>
  <center>
      <img class ="img2" src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/istock-unfinished-business-hed-2015.jpg" />
  </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you detect the hover on the .bigbox div, you can easily apply style for any descendant of the div.

```css
.img2 {
    /*simplified for this demo*/
    opacity:0.2;
}
.h2title {
    /*simplified for this demo*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    color:black;
    margin: 50px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.bigbox:hover .img2 {
    opacity:0.9;
}

.bigbox:hover .h2title {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox"><a class="h2title" href="#"> <h2>Some Text on this guy's head</h2></a>
    <img class ="img2" src="http://www.adweek.com/files/imagecache/node-blog/blogs/istock-unfinished-business-hed-2015.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "previous sibling" selector. To make h2 tag white color, you can use Steven Manuel solution.

On a related note, `~` is for general successor sibling (meaning the element comes after this one, but not necessarily immediately after) and is a CSS3 selector. + is for next sibling and is CSS2.1.

More details on [Is there a “previous sibling” CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [css3_gen_sibling](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_gen_sibling)

Check my demo for CSS selector previous sibling here: https://jsfiddle.net/x7kqveky/

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

> Try Something like this.

```css
.a:hover + .b {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">First Div</div>
<div class="b">Second Div</div>
```